# Rolling median in python

Tags: python, finance, quantitative-finance, pandas

I have some stock data based on daily close values.  I need to be able to insert these values into a python list and get a median for the last 30 closes.  Is there a python library that does this?

Comment: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577059-running-median/

Comment: It would be more efficient to do the median of the last 29 values. If 30 was an arbitrary choice, you can avoid having to calculate the mean of the middle two if you choose an odd-numbered window size.

Comment: That's why it's nice to have a specialized library so I don't have to manipulate my preferences over the fear that there is a bug in my algorithm.  It looks like pandas handles arbitrary intervals and timestamps the data.  Nice!

Comment: Agreed, but my point was really: Understanding the algorithms you're using can often lead to improved performance. Worth bearing in mind if/when you nede to optomise further down the road...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you considered [pandas](http://pandas.sourceforge.net/)?  It is based on `numpy` and can automatically associate timestamps with your data, and discards any unknown dates as long as you fill it with `numpy.nan`. It also offers some rather powerful graphing via matplotlib.

Basically it was designed for financial analysis in python.

Comment: Nice: http://pandas.sourceforge.net/generated/pandas.stats.api.rolling_median.html?highlight=median#pandas.stats.api.rolling_median

Answer (score 12):

In pure Python, having your data in a Python list `a`, you could do

```
median = sum(sorted(a[-30:])[14:16]) / 2.0
```

(This assumes `a` has at least 30 items.)

Using the NumPy package, you could use

```
median = numpy.median(a[-30:])
```

Answer (score 2):

isn't the median just the middle value in a sorted range?

so, assuming your list is `stock_data`:

```
last_thirty = stock_data[-30:]
median = sorted(last_thirty)[15]
```

Now you just need to get the off-by-one errors found and fixed and also handle the case of `stock_data` being less than 30 elements...

let us try that here a bit:

```
def rolling_median(data, window):
    if len(data) < window:
       subject = data[:]
    else:
       subject = data[-30:]
    return sorted(subject)[len(subject)/2]
```

Comment: For an list with an even number of values the median is the mean of the two middle values.

Answer (score 1):

#found this helpful:

```
import numpy as np
list=[10,20,30,40,50]

med=[]
j=0
for x in list:
    sub_set=list[0:j+1]
    median = np.median(sub_set)
    med.append(median)    
    j+=1
print(med)
```

Comment: `np` is not defined. I guess this is supposed to be numpy? Please add `import numpy as np` to your code.

Answer (score 0):

While the answers are correct, the rolling median would have a huge overhead of calling `np.median` within a loop. Here is a much faster method with `w*|x|` space complexity.

```
import numpy as np

def moving_median(x, w):
    shifted = np.zeros((len(x)+w-1, w))
    shifted[:,:] = np.nan
    for idx in range(w-1):
        shifted[idx:-w+idx+1, idx] = x
    shifted[idx+1:, idx+1] = x
    # print(shifted)
    medians = np.median(shifted, axis=1)
    for idx in range(w-1):
        medians[idx] = np.median(shifted[idx, :idx+1])
        medians[-idx-1] = np.median(shifted[-idx-1, -idx-1:])
    return medians[(w-1)//2:-(w-1)//2]

moving_median(np.arange(10), 4)
# Output
array([0.5, 1. , 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8. ])
```

The output has the same length as the input vector.
Rows with less than one entry will be ignored and with half of them nans (happens only for an even window-width), only the first option will be returned. Here is the shifted_matrix from above with the respective median values:

```
[[ 0. nan nan nan] -> -
 [ 1.  0. nan nan] -> 0.5
 [ 2.  1.  0. nan] -> 1.0
 [ 3.  2.  1.  0.] -> 1.5
 [ 4.  3.  2.  1.] -> 2.5
 [ 5.  4.  3.  2.] -> 3.5
 [ 6.  5.  4.  3.] -> 4.5
 [ 7.  6.  5.  4.] -> 5.5
 [ 8.  7.  6.  5.] -> 6.5
 [ 9.  8.  7.  6.] -> 7.5
 [nan  9.  8.  7.] -> 8.0
 [nan nan  9.  8.] -> -
 [nan nan nan  9.]]-> -
```

The behaviour can be changed by adapting the final slice `medians[(w-1)//2:-(w-1)//2]`.

**Benchmark:**

```
%%timeit
moving_median(np.arange(1000), 4)
# 267 µs ± 759 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Alternative approach: (the results will be shifted)

```
def moving_median_list(x, w):
    medians = np.zeros(len(x))
    for j in range(len(x)):
        medians[j] = np.median(x[j:j+w])
    return medians

%%timeit
moving_median_list(np.arange(1000), 4)
# 15.7 ms ± 115 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Both algorithms have a linear time complexity.
Therefore, the function `moving_median` will be the faster option.

Comment: Let me propose a pair of tips: if indeed hunting for speed, never allow mem-I/O to allocate ALAP, pre-allocate & re-use all computing resources ( both for "data" & "medians". Reference passing is fastest way to instruct fun/lambda what to process ) - cardinal when growing from schoolbook-sized sketches, consisting of a few SLOCs. Next - before resorting to scripted iterator, test the numpy-smart tooling (where available) - here, using native numpy STRIDING-tricks, on w-idth depth, formulated as a full-VECTORISED filling median-array from smart-strided view on x-data. Test it & you will love it

Comment: `np` is not defined. I guess this is supposed to be numpy? Please add `import numpy as np` to your code.